# How can I ignore HTML Tags which are written between other HTML-Tags in Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am parsing HTML documents with Beautiful Soup.
I am extracting the `<p>` tags from the documents.
However between the `<p>` tags are other tags like `<a href = 'bla'> bla <a>`.
The problem is my code extracts these `<a>` tags too, when I want to ignore them.

Example:

```
html = ['<p> text text text. (<a href = bla> bla </a>) </p>']
```

My code:

```
Reintext = []
for line in html:
    try:
        soup = bs(line, 'lxml')
        re = ','.join(p.text for p in soup.find_all('p', class_=False, id=False))
        j = re.replace('\n', '')
        g = ' '.join(j.split())
        Reintext.append(g)
    except:
        print(line)
```

Output

```
Reintext = ['text text text. ( bla ) ,']
```

So how can I ignore the (bla) part in the Reintext output?

Comment: `print(soup.find('p').get_text())` See [docs here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using `find` function and keeping only `NavigableString` objects (meaning plain text in HTML).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import bs4
html = ['<p> text text text. (<a href = bla> bla </a>) </p>']

for line in html:
    soup = bs(line, 'lxml')
    external_span = soup.find('p')
    text = []
    for x in external_span:
        if isinstance(x, bs4.element.NavigableString):
            text.append(x.strip())
    print(" ".join(text))
#text text text. ( )
```